# Add DataGridView using Telerik DOCK Libraries

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datagridview, telerik

```
        RadDock radDock1 = new RadDock();
        radDock1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(radDock1);

        ToolWindow window1 = new ToolWindow();
        window1.Name = "window1";
        radDock1.DockWindow(window1, DockPosition.Left);

        DocumentWindow document1 = new DocumentWindow();
        document1.Name = "document1";
        radDock1.AddDocument(document1);
```

I am using RadControls for WinForms, u can find in the provided link:
http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/overview.html

In document1 , I want to dynamically add my DataGridView that is default provided by VS2010. How can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a grid all you need is this:

```
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
document1.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
```

However, the grid will be empty. To fill it, just set the DataSource property.

```
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
List<Colors> colors = new List<Colors>();
colors.Add(new Colors("Red"));
colors.Add(new Colors("Green"));
colors.Add(new Colors("Blue"));
colors.Add(new Colors("Yellow"));
colors.Add(new Colors("Pink"));
dataGridView1.DataSource = colors;

document1.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
```

This is using a simple class Colors.

```
public class Colors
{
  public Colors(string color)
  {
    Color = color;
  }
  public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

It should produce a form that looks like this:

[image]